# VirtualizingPanel in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, stackpanel, virtualizingstackpanel

I've started exploring the Data and UI virtualization features in WPF recently and stumbled upon something strange.

I created a `DataGrid`'s with `Virtualizing` enabled and filled it with a list with 1,000,000 items. This works great and amazingly fast.

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="employees" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
                                 VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                                 VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
</Grid>
```

However, when I nested it under a `StackPanel` it loads for over a minute until I get `OutOfMemoryException`. I've set the same `VirtualizingPanel` properties on the `StackPanel` as well but it doesn't help.

Is this behaviour intentional or am I missing something basic here? And how can I manage to support data virtualization in nested controls?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a `StackPanel` is an "infinite container" (notice the quotes), in the sense that it does NOT impose a limit in the size of its children, like a `Grid` or `DockPanel` does.

What this means in terms of UI virtualization is that, since your `DataGrid` is not limited in `Height`, it will grow endlessly and render all it's items, effectively losing UI virtualization.

See [MSDN: WPF Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

The bottom line is that you need make sure you use the appropiate layout containers, depending on your needs.